# Get list information from another SharePoint list

Tags: list, lookup-column

i have a SharePoint list called “HR”, it lists our employees and all personal information about them. On this list, I want to display whether the employee have borrowed any equipment home from the company.

The items that the employees borrow are stored in another SharePoint list called "Borrowed Equipment". It contains several yes/no boxes for each borrowed equipment and a text field for any comments.

Now, when an employee leaves the company, i want a list of borrowed equipment to display on the HR list, under the employees list element.

Is this possible in any way?.

Comment: How are the lists related already?  Does the "Borrowed Equipment" have a lookup column to the "HR" list?

Comment: Also, which version of SharePoint are using, on-premises or online, modern or classic?

Comment: It's SharePoint Online Modern view, and the lists are not related in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the Lookup columns in the HR List, Select source list as **Borrowed Equipment** and select the fields that you want to show in **HR** List

Comment: I've tried that, but the field is blank, even though i check the other list and confirmed that it contains data. I'm thinking that i need to tell the Lookup, that it needs to get the data from the same emplyee on the other list?. Or have i misunderstood what the Lookup feature is supposed to do?.

Comment: @user2492871 - Lookup column is just like Primary and foreign key concept. It should pull the data from your Parent list if your Primary key matches with the Destination List (Foreign key).

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a relationship between the two lists, you would need to add a [Lookup column](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632) from one to the other.

Which list you choose to put the lookup column on could be a matter of debate, however, I would suggest adding a Lookup column on the "Borrowed Equipment" list pointing to "HR".  In general, when choosing the direction of the lookup, if you have a one-to-many relationship, in **most** cases you will want to put the Lookup column on the list that is on the "many" side of that relationship, pointing to the "one", or in other words, the child records point to the parent.

So, if you add the Lookup to your "Borrowed Equipment", then whenever someone adds a new Borrowed Item, they effectively get an Employee choice list sourced from the connected "HR" list.  If you already have a text field for employee name or something in HR, you should remove that and just use the lookup column.

Once that relationship is configured, you can create a new "[grouped view](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-grouping-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-18548b63-a869-4fcf-89b1-ba3d04784df7)" in your "Borrowed Equipment" list that groups by the HR Lookup column.  Thus giving your users a quick way to see what any given employee has borrowed.